# Css drop down menu not showing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a traditional CSS dropdown menu. However for some strange reason the dropdown part outside the main main manu in not showing.

I am including the code below.

```
<div class="mainMenu" id="mainMenu">
   <ul>
       <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem1"> <a href="./squadra.html">Squadra</a> </li>
       <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem2"> <a href="./biglietti.html">Biglietti</a> </li>
       <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem3"> <a href="abbonamenti.html">Abbonamenti</a> </li>
       <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem4"> <a href="ritiro.html">Ritiro</a> </li>
       <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem5"> <a href="fidelityCard.html">Fidelity Card</a> </li>
       <li class="menuItem active accountMenuItem" id="menuItem7"> <span> <a href="account.html">Account</a> </span>
         <div>
             <ul class="mainSubMenu">
                <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="profilo.html">Profilo</a></li>
                <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="datiFatturazione.html">Dati Fatturazione</a></li>
                <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="storicoTifoso.html">Storico Tifoso</a></li>
                <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="esci.html">Esci</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In my css

```
#mainMenu
{
   font-size: 0.85em;
   padding:10px 0 0px 0;
   border:white 2px;
   background: rgba(17, 91, 164, .6);
   height:50px;
 /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

#mainMenu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#mainMenu ul li
{

    height:20px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.7em;
    margin-left:.5em;
    margin-right:.5em;
    max-width:180px;
    padding:15px !important;
}

#mainMenu ul li:hover, #mainMenu ul li.active
{
   background: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1);
   border-top: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1) 15px;
}

#mainMenu ul li a, #mainMenu ul li span a
{
    color:brown;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.accountMenuItem
{
    /*margin-left:88px !important;*/
}

.mainSubMenu
{
   display:none;
   z-index:100;
   background: rgba(17, 91, 164, .6) !important;
   color:black !important;
   font-size:1em!important;
}


.mainMenu:hover   .mainSubMenu {display:block }

.mainMenu ul li:hover > ul{display:block;}

#mainMenu ul li ul{position: relative; left:-1px; top:98%; background: rgba(17, 91, 164, .6); color:black;}

#mainMenu ul ul ul{position: relative; left:98%; top:-1px;}
#mainMenu ul ul{
    width:119.7px;
}
```

what am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help me?

Thanks very much in advacance for your time.

Comment: Check out this fiddle and see if helps with your structure and css
http://jsfiddle.net/uYd9u/20/

Answer (score 0):

It is showing - it's just that your text is the same color as the background. Give your page a background color, and you'll see your menu and submenu. (add: body { background-color:#999999; } )

It does need a little positioning, and clean-up, but the show/hide is working.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, but I had few days off... Thanks for your response. I have tried your suggestion, however on my webpage it is not working. I have looked at all possible causes but to no avail. I have uploaded the page @ http://prova.webuda.com/_profilo.html. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Simple fix: #contentarea has overflow:hidden. Remove that and your menu will display as expected.

Comment: You will want to set the z-index of the submenu to a high number so that it appears above all other elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

On your css do 2 things first give background color, second change this line:

```
.mainMenu:hover   .mainSubMenu {display:block }

to

#menuItem7:hover   .mainSubMenu {display:block }
```

Rest you can adjust the css according to your need.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I have tried your suggestion, however on my webpage it is not working. I have looked at all possible causes but to no avail. I have uploaded the page @ http://prova.webuda.com/_profilo.html. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: I have found 2 things first your HTML of dropdown is broken 2nd some one your other stylesheet files are conflicting with your menu css. Try to check your menu by disabling all the css except <link rel="stylesheet" href="risorse/newStyle.css" type="text/css">  You will see your menu working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   #mainMenu ul ul {
display: none;
    }

#mainMenu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#mainMenu{
margin-left:400px;}
   #mainMenu ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;

    }
#mainMenu ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
    #mainMenu ul li {
float: left;
    }
#mainMenu ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    #mainMenu ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

#mainMenu ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
    #mainMenu ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
#mainMenu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    #mainMenu ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        #mainMenu ul ul li a:hover {
            background:red;
        }
    #mainMenu ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="mainMenu" id="mainMenu">
        <ul>
          <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem1"> <a href="./squadra.html">Squadra</a> </li>
          <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem2"> <a href="./biglietti.html">Biglietti</a> </li>
          <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem3"> <a href="abbonamenti.html">Abbonamenti</a> </li>
          <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem4"> <a href="ritiro.html">Ritiro</a> </li>
          <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem5"> <a href="fidelityCard.html">Fidelity</a> </li>






        <li class="menuItem active accountMenuItem" id="menuItem7"> <span> 
         <a  href="account.html">Account</a> </span>

            <ul class="mainSubMenu">
               <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="prof.html">Profilo</a></li>
        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="datiFatturazione.html">Dati /a>/li>
        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui"  href="storico\.html">Storico</a></li>
                <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="esci.html">Esci</a></li>
            </ul>





          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>




  REMOVE div tag in the 2nd ul
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, but I had few days off... Thanks for your response. I have tried your suggestion, however on my webpage it is not working. I have looked at all possible causes but to no avail. To clear any doubt I have substituted my HTML and CSS code with yours, but the problem remains... I have uploaded the page @ http://prova.webuda.com/_profilo.html. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Sir, it is working for me. You REMOVE div tag in the 2nd ul of your code. Or simply copy paste my code, I have submenu under " Accounts" tab. Please check it again.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TL94n/  check this, scroll down, under accounts tab it is showing drop-down.(though its format is not correct due to some other reason). it will work in your browser if you copy,paste the code

Comment: You have not added this in your css code:-                               #mainMenu ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    #mainMenu ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I have no doubt it is working for you. The example you posted is working on my pc too. However when I make the chenges to my code nothing changes. I fact to clear any doubts I have changed the relavant Css and HTML code in the page with yours, but to no avail. I have uploaded the page here prova.webuda.com/_profilo.html.